# What is the correct term for those different styled "pop up" boxes and how to implement them?

Tags: javascript, popup

what are these boxes called? (the red error alert one in the image below?
I thought they would be called a pop up box but when i went to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp and learnt how to to code these there is a slight difference. The difference is that the one on the website requires you to close it or accept it's error before continuing. Whereas the one they use in stack overflow and other websites alerts the user but allows you to carry on typing or performing an action rather than having to close it and then continuing.
so can anyone tell me what they are properly referred to as because when i google JavaScript pop up boxes I only get returned stuff like the link above. 
AND can someone link me to a page where I can learn how to do it or start me off with some basic syntax
[image: an image of a red alert box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a bunch of names:

- popup
- popover
- tooltip
- in-page notification
- alert (not to be confused with the `alert` function)

Basically, they're just DOM elements with positioning information and a higher z-index than the elements underneath them. Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("div").style.display = "block";
}, false);
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

```css
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  background-color: #ee0;
  border: 1px solid #aa0;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<div style="display: none" class="popup">I'm the popup</div>
```

Any of a very, very large number of libraries provide utilities for doing them. Two fairly popular ones are [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/), but there are **lots** of others.

Here's a Bootstrap example:

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

And a jQuery UI one:

```js
$(document).tooltip();
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Hover the field for the tooltip:</p>
<label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
```

Comment: thanks. but have you got one like the stackoverflow one where as you leave an area like a textbox, something pops up? i know onfocus is for as you type but i require the attribute that would be something like asyouleavefocus. if you get me

Comment: @BlueShark: The converse of the `focus` event is `blur` (yes, really).

Comment: but you see this webpage: http://jsfiddle.net/ysuw5/. this example shows what happens when the user starts typing. which is great. but i want one where the user leaves the textbox/textarea. has made an error e.g. entered too few characters and an alert comes up saying "you have entered 2 few characters". im about to post a question on it...

Comment: @BlueShark: Again, you'd use `blur` for that.